# Sharing Echo Show Screen on to a monitor. Possible or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, alexa-skills-kit

I am creating a skill for Echo Show which lets user see a lot of information. Now the targeted users for this skill can't be near to the echo show devices all the time as this skill is for bigger places like Airports and Big Malls etc. What I want to do is to project whatever my Echo Show device is doing, onto a larger monitor just like we do it with Google Chromecast. Please let me know how to do this. If it's possible please refer me the docs which I can refer and implement.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible directly at the moment.

I don't know which content you want to show and where it comes from but if all the data on the show comes from your skill I can think of this solution:

1. Implement some sort of account linking, which lets you identify the alexa-user with a user on your website
2. If the skill is called, do a call to your RestAPI containing the data, which you showed in your skill and the user-id
3. Provide a GUI on your website which shows the same data (in the best way dynamically and directly after the API-call from your skill) to the logged-in user.

This would be a (complicated) workaround, but I don't think there is an easier solution to your problem. Anyway, you can suggest the native implementation of your feature [here](https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote).